# Laravel cookies not available in service provider during unit testing

Tags: php, laravel

I have a service provider which instantiates a `CartCookie` class which generates a unique cookie for saving shopping carts. It's a singleton class and it's injected into the service container.

CartCookieServiceProvider.php

```
public function boot(Request $request)
    {
        $this->app->singleton(CartCookie::class, function ($app) use ($request) {
            return new CartCookie($request);
        });
    }
```

CartCookie.php

```
use App\Cart;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CartCookie
{
    private $id;
    private $request;

    function __construct(Request $request)
    {
        $this->request = $request;

        if ($request->cookie('cart_id')) {
            $this->id = $request->cookie('cart_id');
        } else {
            $this->id = $this->generateUniqueCartId();
        }
    }

    public function id()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    private function generateUniqueCartId()
    {
        do {
            $id = md5(time() . 'cart' . rand(100000000000000, 9999999999999999));
        } while (Cart::find($id));

        return $id;
    }
}
```

In the `CartCookie` class I check for the existence of a `cart_id` cookie. Works perfectly fine when using the application!

My issue is that during unit tests, the `cart_id` cookie is empty, but only when the `Request` comes from the service provider. If I obtain the `Request` from a Controller later on in the lifecycle for example, the cookie is present.

Here is an example of a test:

```
/** @test */
    public function get__store_checkout__checkout_displays_database_cart_correctly()
    {
        $cart = $this->createDatabaseCart();

        $cookie = ['cart_id' => Crypt::encrypt($this->cartCookie)];

        $response = $this->call('get', route('root.store.checkout'), [
            'seller_id' => $cart->seller->id,
        ], $cookie);

        $cart->seller->items()->each(function ($item) use ($response) {
            $this->assertContains($beat->item, $response->getContent());
        });
    }
```

I can tell the existence when I `dd()` the request cookies in both the service provider and the controller that handles the cart functionality. For some reason, only during unit tests, the request doesn't contain the cookie yet in the service provider.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: This makes sense because service providers are first loaded and then unit test call to route is executed?

Comment: @DoniiHoho I'm not sure about that, `$this->call()` is starting a whole new request.

Comment: It creates a new request and passes it to the routes but within the same script execution, since you have marked it as a singleton, this is where the issue lies.

Comment: @DoniiHoho Not sure if I'm misunderstanding but I'm not not trying to access the cookie from within the test script itself, I'm accessing from within the new request that's created. That make sense? The new request is a new request and should set up the application exactly how it would if I was going to that URL in the browser.

Comment: No, you are confusing Request Object and Controller calls with actual HTTP requests. The difference is that in your case, service provider is only called once, with HTTP requests service provider is called on each HTTP request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From here: [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/container#binding-basics)

Try:

```
/** @test */
public function get__store_checkout__checkout_displays_database_cart_correctly()
{
    $cart = $this->createDatabaseCart();

    $cookie = ['cart_id' => Crypt::encrypt($this->cartCookie)];

    //@TODO you must get the current request
    //@TODO you must set $cookie to $request
    //Or simply find a way to create the CartCookie you need using the $cookie from above
    $cartCookie = new CartCookie($request);

    //hopefully will swap the CartCookie::class instance
    app()->instance(CartCookie::class, $cartCookie);

    //Now that you have the CartCookie
    $response = $this->call('get', route('root.store.checkout'), [
        'seller_id' => $cart->seller->id,
    ], $cookie);

    $cart->seller->items()->each(function ($item) use ($response) {
        $this->assertContains($beat->item, $response->getContent());
    });
}
```

Comment: Right I get you now. I was under the impression `->call()` was more like an ajax request to it would instantiate the application each time, but now I see otherwise. I have modified the test to pass now using a variation of your example `$cartCookie = app(CartCookie::class); $cartCookie->setId($this->cartCookie); app()->instance(CartCookie::class, $cartCookie);` Not ideal but the test is passing so thanks for your help and teaching me something new :)

Comment: Cheers mate, glad it helped!